# before Remote in Loopback

Tags: loopbackjs, strongloop

I'm trying to use the before Remote hook in loopback to check an user token before the call of my remote method, but the thing is that I can only return a javascript Error, like these.

```
    "error": {
        "statusCode": 401,
        "name": "Error",
        "message": ""
    }
```

This is the code that i'm using in the before remote.

```
Model.beforeRemote('method', function (context, unused, next) {

let token = Model.app.models.Token;
let id = context.args.Id;

let date = moment();
Rx.Observable.fromPromise(token.find({
    where: {
        and: [
            { id: id, },
            { expiration: { gt: date } }
        ]
    }
})).subscribe((token => {
    if (token.length > 0) {
        next();
    } else {
        let err = new Error();
        err.status = 401;
        delete err.stack;
        return next()
    }
}))
});
```

And I need a "custom" response that isn't an error, something like these.

```
    {
      "success": false,
      "data": {
        "service": "self",
        "operation": "rest",
        "code": "unauthorized"
      },
      "message": "Invalid token"
    }
```

I tried with the after Remote hook and I can change the response to get something like that, but I want to get a quicker response in the case that the token is invalid.

Is there any way to achieve this with the before hook? or I had to use after hook?

Thanks

Comment: I am assuming you have used Loopback's ACL, would you mind telling us the reason why the default error response is not enough for your requirements?

Comment: and please show us the existing code you have, using the beforeRemote method.

Comment: I'm not using Loopback's ACL. I have to replicate a rest service to make an app work, the user's token comes from another service. The app needs an specific response with an specific status code to trigger an event and logout the user when the token is outdated.

Comment: Added the code with the beforeRemote hook.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to pass the error to the next function:

`return next(err)`

Comment: I tried that, and gives me the first response structure (the error one), but it doesn't trigger the event in the app to logout the user.

Comment: In your question, you didn't mention about logging out the user. Calling the function next by passing an error as its first parameter makes Loopback API endpoint return immediately without executing the remote method. You can always log out the user programmatically and then call next. Check this out: https://apidocs.strongloop.com/loopback/#user-logout

Comment: The main thing is that the login comes from another webservice that i didn't have access to, i can only save the token it gives me and verify if it exists. And i can't change the code from the Mobile App, so i had to return a response like in the second example. I'm currently doing it with the after remote hook. but it would be nice if i could make it work before calling the remotes.